# How do I store "arrays" of statistical models?

Tags: r

Is there an R data structure into which I can store a number of `lm` or `lmer` or `gam` objects?  `J` has boxed arrays, and one can put pretty much anything into the cells of such a boxed array.  I think that's what I'm looking for in R.

I've tried lists and data frames, to no avail; I thought lists might work.

```
> testlist <- list()
> testlist[1] <- subject1.2008.gam
Warning message:
In testlist[1] <- subject1.2008.gam :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>
```

Alternatively, is there a way to create and use a variable name on the LHS of `<-`?

Finally, perhaps you have a better idiom for me to consider.  I'm trying to create a collection of GAM models over a set of subjects and years, for example.  Later, I want to be able to plot or predict from those models, so I think I need to keep the full model around.  Because I want to be able to use this code with different data sets later, I'd like not to hard-code the names of the `gam` objects nor their number.

While I started by putting the `gam()` call in a loop, I think one of the `apply()` functions might work better, but I still need a place to store the output.

Comment: You might also want to look into plyr, which makes this sort of model fitting very very easy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need the `[[` operator for lists, try

```
testlist[[1]] <- subject1.2008.gam
```

The other usual tip is that you may want to pre-allocate if you know how many elements you may have, I often do

```
testlist <- vector(mode="list", length=N)
```

for a given `N`.

Comment: Both answers are essentially the same and seem to solve my problem; thanks!

Comment: You can also use a string for the list index - this is much more useful and readable later. e.g. `models[[model_name]] <- model`.

Comment: Doing something like testlist[[1]] <- subject1.2008.gam wasn't working for my lm() model objects. I wasn't able to then use fitted(testlist[[1]]), for example. Instead, I used this construction:     testlist <- list(subject1.2008.gam=subject1.2008.gam)

Answer (score 3):

Use `[[` to access the list elements:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0) ## simulate some data... 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)

mods <- vector(mode = "list", length = 3)
for(i in seq_along(mods)) {
    mods[[i]] <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = dat)
}
```

Giving:

```
> str(mods, max = 1)
List of 3
 $ :List of 43
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "gam" "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 43
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "gam" "glm" "lm"
 $ :List of 43
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "gam" "glm" "lm"
```

Comment: Looks like I beat you by a minute or two :)  But just gave you an upvote for the nice example with `gam()` models.

Comment: @Dirk Full disclosure: I just stole that from Simon's example in `?gam` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers show how to use an index and `[[ ]]` but you can also do something like

```
x1  <- 1:10  ; y1  <-  30*x1 + rnorm(10)
x2  <- rnorm(20)  ; y2  <- 30*x2 + 100 + rnorm(20)
lm1 <- lm(y1 ~ x1); lm2 <- lm(y2 ~ x2) 

testlist <- list( A = lm1, Z = lm2 ) 
testlist$Z
testlist$Z$model$y2
```