# How to handover R list object to R transform in Code Workbook

Tags: palantir-foundry

I estimate a polr model with R in foundry code workbook. After estimation I want to handover the model object to another R transform. Estimation works fine. Handover not.

Example:

global code

```
library(MASS)
```

transform code

```
model <- function(modeldata) {
    df <- modeldata
   
    model = polr(answer ~  eos_ratio,
                 data = df,
                 Hess = TRUE)

    return(model)
}
```

Error message

```
Function should return a data frame or FoundryObject or NULL.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you return something from Code Workbooks in Foundry, it's expected for you to be returning a data frame, a FoundryObject or a raw file written to a dataset. For saving down models, users generally use Foundry Machine Learning (FoundryML) but it currently doesn't support R officially.  Please contact support for the specifics and if you face issues since I realize there might be a lot of pain here.

My R is a bit rusty, but there are a couple of (hacky) alternatives:

From the documentation https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/code-workbook/transforms-unstructured/#unstructured-files-in-r , here is how you save down a .rds file:

```
write_rds_file <- function(r_dataframe) {
    output <- new.output()
    output_fs <- output$fileSystem()
    saveRDS(r_dataframe, output_fs$get_path("my_RDS_file.rds", 'w'))

}
```

You can something similar with `rda`: [Reusing a Model Built in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118074/reusing-a-model-built-in-r)

The other option is store the model parameters in a dataframe:
[How do I store lm object in a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627179/how-do-i-store-lm-object-in-a-data-frame-in-r)

You can then recreate the model using those parameters.