# Output 'h2o' function results to a vector

Tags: r, gbm, h2o

I have a question similar to this ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599896/how-do-i-store-arrays-of-statistical-models)) except that my question refers to the java tool 'h2o' and its connection to 'r'.

In particular I want to assign a "h2o" object to part of a vector (or structure or array.  I want to loop through and store several of them without having to manually enumerate.

I tried the solution at the link but it does not work for 'h2o' objects.

Here is my longer code (warts and all):

```
#libraries
library(h2o)      #for tree control

#specify data
mydata <- iris[iris$Species!="setosa",]
mydata$Species <- as.factor(as.character(mydata$Species))

#most informative variable is petal length
x1 <- mydata$Petal.Length
x2 <- mydata$Petal.Width

#build classes
C <- matrix(0,nrow=length(x1),ncol=1)
idx1 <- which(mydata$Species == "versicolor",arr.ind=T)
idx2 <- which(mydata$Species != "versicolor",arr.ind=T)
C[idx1] <- +1
C[idx2] <- 0

#start h2o
localH2O = h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

# Run regression GBM on iris.hex data
irisPath = system.file("extdata", "iris.csv", package="h2o")
iris.hex = h2o.uploadFile(localH2O, path = irisPath)
names(iris.hex) <- c("Sepal.Length",
                     "Sepal.Width",
                     "Petal.Length",
                     "Petal.Width",
                     "Species" )

iris2 <- iris
iris2$Species <- unclass(iris$Species)
iris2.hex <- as.h2o(iris2)
iris.hex$Species <- as.factor(iris2.hex$Species)

independent <- c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")
dependent <- "Species"

mare <- numeric()
mae <- matrix(1,nrow=10,ncol=1)

est2.h2o <- vector(mode="list", length=150)

for (i in 1:150){

     est2.h2o[[i]] <- h2o.gbm(y = dependent, 
                         x = independent, 
                         training_frame = iris.hex,
                         distribution="AUTO",
                         ntrees = i, max_depth = 3, min_rows = 2,
                         learn_rate = 0.5)


     pred <- h2o.predict(est2.h2o,newdata=iris.hex)

     err <- iris2$Species-(as.data.frame(pred)$predict+1)

     mae[i] <- mean(abs(err))
     mare[i] <- mean(abs(err)/iris2$Species)

     print(c(i,log10(mae[i])))

}
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error in paste0("Predictions/models/", object@model_id, "/frames/", newdata@frame_id) : 
  trying to get slot "model_id" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots
```

My intention is to have a list/structure/array of GBM's that I can then run predict against for the whole data-set, and cull the less informative ones.  I'm trying to make a decent "random forest of gbt's" following the steps of  Eugene Tuv.  I don't have his code.

**Questions:**
Is there a proper way to pack the h2o gbm along with a few (hundred) of its buddies, into a single store in r?

If the referenced object is thrown away in java, making this sort of approach unfeasible, is there a feasible variation using the 'gbm' library?  If I end up having to use gbm, what is the speed difference vs. h2o?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the parameters you're using in h2o.gbm?

Comment: doesn't run just yet, I think I need an API key. But if you `lapply` on 1:150, you'll get your list, then I believe `sapply(est.h2o, h2o.predict, newdata = iris.hex)` should generate a data.frame, and then you can do the remainder as vector calculations. The error you're getting is from using the wrong type object

Comment: nah.  R and h2o work together but need rjava with the 32 bit version.  I have a 64 bit cpu, but the r itself is 32 bit, and there is some bitwise compatibility issue.  I will see if I can wrap it in a "sapply".

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense, I'll try it out, h2o looks neat

Comment: There are 2 reasons I like h2o.  1) it will use all my cores and most of my memory while r doesn't - which makes it substantially faster and 2) other tools wrapper it like domino, amazon. (It also works with java, scala, r and python, but it had me at 'r'.)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the exact parameters you're using, My guess is that the problem is that you're using `sapply` and not `lapply`.

`sapply` often attempts to simplify the result, which is good most of the time. But, if you want something that can contain any kind of object, then you want a list.

if we define `paramListList` as a list, where each entry is a list containing your parameters for h2o.gbm:

Ex:

```
paramListList <- list(list(x = xVALUES1, 
                           y = yVALUES1, 
                           training_frame = tfVALUES1, 
                           model_id = miVALUES1, 
                           checkpoint = checkVALUES1),
                      list(x = xVALUES2, 
                           y = yVALUES2, 
                           training_frame = tfVALUES2, 
                           model_id = miVALUES2, 
                           checkpoint = checkVALUES2),
                     )
```

then you can do the following:

```
lapply(paramListList, function(paramlist) do.call(h2o.gbm, paramlist))
```

which will put all of your results in that one list